# browserify module loading into function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, browserify, require

i have an app.js which is the main file for my webapplication. It initialize the UI and loads different modules. At the moment it is one big file with all the code. I want to refactor this and split the functions into independant modules and then bundle them with browserify. App.js has a dependency to jquery and some modules too.

i have defined the `browser`section in `package.json`

```
"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "jquery-ui": "./static/js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "App": "./static/js/app.js",
    "myModule": "./static/js/myModule.js"
}
```

Also i use `browserify-shim` to load some jquery plugins which can't be loaded without.

For `browserify-shim` i've defined a config section:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "jquery-ui": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
    ]
    },
    "bootstrap": {
        "depends": [
            "jquery:$"
        ]
    },
    "dropdown": {
       "depends": [
           "jquery:$"
       ]
    },
    "App": {
        "exports": "App",
        "depends": [
            "jquery:$"
        ]
    },
}
```

My `entry.js` file

```
var $ = require("jquery");
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
var App = require('./app.js');
require('./some jquery plugins');
```

In my `app.js`

```
var App = function(){
    some code...

    var myModule = require('./myModule.js');
    myModule();

    some code...
    return {
        init: function() {
            someFunctions();
            someFunctions(); 
        }
    }
}();

$(function(){ App.init(); });
```

In my `myModule.js`

```
module.exports = function() {
    some code with jquery...    
};
```

It bundles correctly but if i load the page i'll get

`app.js:14Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './myModule.js'`

And if i look in the sources in my browser it tells me:

`var myModule = __browserify_shim_require__('./myModule.js');`

so it seems browserify can't load the module correctly in this scope.

What am i doing wrong? Does i forget something? I think i don't need to shim my own module because i can use commonjs format for browserify. Do i have to use another pattern in this context?

Thanks for help in advance!

**Edit:**

I don't have a solution yet. i refactored the whole thing and now i don't need browserify shim anymore. You can add most plugins without it.

Comment: Try removing `"myModule"` from the `"browser"` configuration.

Comment: I figured out that it works if I remove  `App` from `browserify-shim` but then all the jquery plugins etc doesn't work anymore :(